# string: extract a word from sentence

Tags: string, c#-4.0

Here is my sample of inputs entered by user as a list of task for a day

```
Meeting with developer 60min
Schedule a GoTo Meeting to discuss weekly sprint 45min
15min to code integration.
```

how we could extract the word 60min, 45min and 15min for my calculation.

Comment: This is an ideal use case of regular expressions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Regex.Match("Meeting with developer 60min", @"(\d+min)").Groups[1].ToString();
```

Comment: It is the value inside the bracket -> (\d+min). So the value you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

```
var output = input.Split(' ', '\n', '\r').Where(i => i.Contains("min"));
```

Edited to deal with line breaks

Comment: i could get that in output[0]... also sometimes it throws an exception "enumeration yields no result" how could i get that in string and null

Comment: Try DefaultIfEmpty () at the end of the expression

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
    string s = "Meeting with developer 60min "+
          "Schedule a GoTo Meeting to discuss weekly sprint 45min "+
          "15min to code integration.";
        foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(s, @"(?<!\w)60\w+"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
        }

        foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(s, @"(?<!\w)15\w+"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
        }

        foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(s, @"(?<!\w)45\w+"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
        }
```

or in a short

```
var output = s.Split(' ').Where(i => i.Contains("min") || i.StartsWith("60") ||    i.StartsWith("15") || i.StartsWith("45"));
            foreach (var o in output)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(o);
            }
```